# how remove the chmod u+x <filename> data of a custom command file deleted on Linux

Tags: command-line

I have installed custom commands on Linux. I would now remove one of them. How do that please?

I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jP4wxxg1gx0) in order to create customs functions in my CLI. The objective is to ease my workflow.

The process is the following :

- create a file in a specific directory with a script inside
- run the command `sudo chmod u+x <filename>`
- modify the .bashrc directory to the path of the custom commands.

*Edit : I have run the command on the script and I assume it have put some data in my system and this is that data that I want remove*

Comment: This is too vague - please [edit] your post and explain exactly what did to install these commands.

Comment: We aren't sure which your talking about but do `which <command_name>` so we know where it is?

Comment: I have modified my topic

Comment: You added these custom commands. So you are the only one that can know what to remove again. You refer to "a file in a specific directory with a script". What prevents you from removing that file that you do not want anymore? Sorry, if you remain vague, our answer can only be more vague.

Comment: I mean, I have run the chmod u+x <filename> command on the script and I assume it have put some data in my system and this is that data that I want remove, sorry to have been vague

Comment: File permissions are stored in an inode and this is what you actually remove when you delete a file, so you don't need to worry about that. Take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/555790/where-does-ubuntu-save-user-permission-of-a-file to see which metadata of a file are stored in the inode.

Answer (score 1):

If you added custom commands by placing a script in a specific directory, making it executable and then adjust your $PATH to include that specific directory, then the process to remove one of these custom commands simply involves deleting the specific script.

The name of your custom command is the file name of the script. Commands indeed are in a majority of cases names of executable files on your system. These executable files can be compiled binary files, but can also be scripts.

You can find out where your command resides with the command `which`. For example

`$ which firefox
/usr/bin/firefox'

This learns me that the full patname of the executable for the command "firefox" is /usr/bin/firefox. (thus, the executable `firefox` resides in the folder `bin` under the folder `usr` in the root directory `\`, i.e. "Computer" in many graphical file managers).

Carry out this command substituting the name of the command you want to remove instead of 'firefox'.

`which <name_of_your_custom_command>`

The command will reveal you the full pathname of the command. Then you can remove the file with the `rm` (remove) command.